# Add new column to SQLite in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm trying to insert two new column to my SQLite database if the column is not available. Everything goes great and also the 'added' BOOL is YES. But these columns are not on my table !

```
-(void)checkColumnExists
{
    NSString *dbPath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movieData.sqlite"];
    const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *contactDB;

    sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB);

    sqlite3_stmt *selectStmt;

    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT borrowMovie from myMovies";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
        //ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD COLUMN COLNew {type};
        const char *sqlStatement1 = "ALTER TABLE myMovies ADD COLUMN borrowMovie TEXT, borrowDate TEXT";
        BOOL added = sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, sqlStatement1, -1, &selectStmt, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you prepare the statement, and then.... nothing.  You haven't read how to use sqlite3 properly at all.

Comment: Yes thats the problem , do you have a link or something to follow ? @Droppy

Comment: Here's [one](http://www.wassen.net/sqlite-c.html).  I simply googled for "using sqlite3_prepare_v2".

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `sqlite3_step()` at least once, after the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`. This is the function that actually executes the query. If you're reading some `SELECT` results, you will need to call that function multiple times (for each row), but if you're just executing a query without results, exactly single call is required.

Comment: You must *not* call `sqlite3_step()` if `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` returns an error (which it does in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out the problem:

1. As @Droppy said I just prepared the statement and then nothing.
2. As @Googie said, I have to use sqlite3_step() at least once.
3. I can't add multiple columns at once and I have to add them one by one.

so the code is,

```
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE myMovies ADD COLUMN borrowMovie TEXT"];
        //
        const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
}
```